# dimension of intersection of subspaces in $\Bbb R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

if $U$ and $V$ are two distinct 2- dimensional subspaces of $\Bbb R^4$, then what values can the dimension of the intersection of $U$ and $V$ take?

I know there are many questions like this,but I still have some doubt. 2- dimensional spaces have to be planes and intersection of two 2- dimensional planes has to be a line, correct?

they cant be parallel planes since, they have $0$ in common, so their intersection should be a line and only a line, correct? I need some geometrical view about the solution.

Comment: You’re working in $\mathbb R^4$, not $\mathbb R^3$, so the intersection can be something other than a line.

Answer (score 0):

Since the we are dealing with subspaces there intersection is a subspace and must include 0, thus it can't be empty. Since they are required to be $\textit{distinct}$ subspaces the intersection can't be dimension 2, because otherwise the intersection would be the whole of the subspaces. So the only posibilities are 0 or 1. Both of these are possible and I give examples of each below.

0-dim: Let $U=\{(x,y,0,0):x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}\subset\mathbb{R}^4$ and $V=\{(0,0,w,z):w,z\in\mathbb{R}\}\subset\mathbb{R}^4$

1 dim: Let $U=\{(x,y,0,0):x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}\subset\mathbb{R}^4$ and $V=\{(0,y,w,0):y,w\in\mathbb{R}\}\subset\mathbb{R}^4$